# Interpolate function in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets to log my water usage and want to find out how much I have used in a given period by using linear interpolation. I would really like to use a function similar to forecast, but instead of using the entire range to interpolate, just use the nearest points above and below.

I am keen to try and code it myself (have done lots of VBA) but don't know really where to start with google scripts. Does anyone have a starting point for me?

The process I would take is:

```
Interpolate(x, data_y, data_x)


// Check value is within range of known values (could expand function to use closet two values and extrapolate...)
(is X within XMin and XMax)

// Find closet X value below (X1), corresponding Y1

// Find closet X value above (X2), corresponding Y2

Return Y = Y1+(X-X1)*((Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1))
```

Comment: Google apps script uses JavaScript. This might be helpful for your question.

Comment: You might like to start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) and then [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947) function to find the two data points around the day to interpolate for.

With the dates in A:A, usage in B:B and interpolation day in D2:

- E2 `=xlookup(D2,A:A,B:B,NA(),-1)` - usage before
- F2 `=xlookup(D2,A:A,B:B,NA(),1)` - usage after
- G2 `=xlookup(D2,A:A,A:A,,-1)` - date before
- H2 `=xlookup(D2,A:A,A:A,,1)`  - date after
- `=E2+(F2-E2)*((D2-G2)/max(1,H2-G2))` interpolated value (max to prevent division by zero)

And then combined it into one formula to avoid the extra columns:

`=xlookup(D2,A:A,B:B,NA(),-1)+(xlookup(D2,A:A,B:B,NA(),1)-xlookup(D2,A:A,B:B,NA(),-1))*((D2-xlookup(D2,A:A,A:A,,-1))/max(1,xlookup(D2,A:A,A:A,,1)-xlookup(D2,A:A,A:A,,-1)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
function interpolation(x_range, y_range, x_value) {
  var xValue, yValue, xDiff, yDiff, xInt, index, check = 0;
  if(x_value > Math.max.apply(Math, x_range) || x_value < Math.min.apply(Math, x_range)) {
    throw "value can't be interpolated !!";
    return;
  }
  for(var i = 0, iLen = x_range.length; i < iLen-1; i++) {
    if((x_range[i][0] <= x_value && x_range[i+1][0]> x_value) || (x_range[i][0] >= x_value && x_range[i+1][0] < x_value)){
      yValue = y_range[i][0];
      xDiff = x_range[i+1][0] - x_range[i][0];
      yDiff = y_range[i+1][0] - yValue;
      xInt = x_value - x_range[i][0];
      return (xInt * (yDiff / xDiff)) + yValue;
    }
  }
  return y_range[x_range.length-1][0];
}
```

Comment: Some meat(explanations/keypoints/flow) on this bone(code) would go a long way.